# Fill TableSection from Json Response in Swift

Tags: json, uitableview, swift3

How to Populate TableSections with from this JSON Response.

I have implemented the design like the dropdown and having one prototype cell with two labels side by side inside it. **below is the structure of my design**

StudentDetailsSection  V(button)

Father'sDetailsSection V(button)

Mother'sDeatilsSection V(button)

**I am also attaching the screenshot of my design**

[image: SectionDesignImage]

My JSON Response is in structure.

```
{
    "Student_Details":
    [
        {
            "Student_ID": 1,
            "School_ID": 1,
            "FirstName": "Ammu",
            "LastName": "Gopal",
            "Date_Of_Birth": "2017-08-05T00:00:00",
            "Gender": 1,
            "Class": " LKG ",
            "Section": "A",
            "Mother_Tongue": "Tamil",
            "Blood_Group": 1,
            "Place_Of_Birth": "Chennai",
            "Caste": 1,
            "Religion": 1,
            "Special_Person": 1,
            "Languages_Known": "English,Tamil,Hindi",
            "Distance_From_Residence_To_School": "11",
            "Nationality": "Indian",
            "Mode_Of_Transport": "School Transport",
            "RTE": null,
            "StudentStatus": 1,
            "AppliedStatus": null,
            "IsDeleted": null,
            "Father_Name": "Kannan",
            "Father_Mobile": "9845245254",
            "Father_Email": "kannan@gmail.com",
            "Father_Education": "Bsc",
            "Father_Occupation": "Self-employer",
            "Father_Name_Of_The_Organisation": "Bussiness",
            "Father_Designation": "Self-Employer",
            "Father_Annual_Income": "200000",
            "Father_Office_Or_Business_Address": null,
            "Mother_Name": "Mathi",
            "Mother_Mobile": "9845245145",
            "Mother_Email": "mathi@gmail.com",
            "Mother_Education": "B com",
            "Mother_Occupation": "Self Employer",
            "Mother_Name_Of_The_Organisation": "Self Employer",
            "Mother_Designation": "Self Employer",
            "Mother_Annual_Income": "200000",
            "Mother_Office_Or_Business_Address": null,
            "Sibling_Details": null,
            "Land_Line_Number": "044-2121444",
            "Guardian_Name": null,
            "Guardian_Mobile": null,
            "Guardian_Email": null,
            "Relationship": null,
            "Guardian_Education": null,
            "Guardian_Occupation": null,
            "Guardian_Name_Of_The_Organisation": null,
            "Guardian_Designation": null,
            "Guardian_Annual_Income": null,
            "Guardian_Office_Or_Business_Address": null,
            "Guardian_Land_Line_Number": null,
            "LeaveLetterApplied": null,
            "Message": null,
            "Date": null,
            "Notify": null,
            "Status": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**how to fetch data from this jsonresponse and fill the particular section.Hoping for the help.Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have static 3 sections:

1) Its a good habit to declare constants.

```
let SEC_STUDENT = 0
let SEC_FATHER  = 1
let SEC_MOTHER  = 2
```

2) Get array from response

```
enum Student_Key : String
{
    case ID = "Student_ID"
    case FirstName = "FirstName"
    case LastName = "LastName"
    //Define all keys so on
}

enum Father_Key : String
{
    case Name = "Father_Name"
    case Mobile = "Father_Mobile"
    //Define all keys so on
}

enum Mother_Key : String
{
    case Name = "Mother_Name"
    case Mobile = "Mother_Mobile"
    //Define all keys so on
}


//Define global 

var arrStudent : Array<[String:String]> = []
var arrMother : Array<[String:String]> = []
var arrFather : Array<[String:String]> = []

//Add new method to parse response

func parseData(response : [String:Any]) {


    let arrayData = response["Student_Details"] as! [Any]

    //You can load only one record in your current way.
    let studentData = arrayData[0] as! [String:Any]

    arrStudent.append(["key":Student_Key.ID.rawValue ,
                       "value" : String(describing: studentData[Student_Key.ID.rawValue])])
    arrStudent.append(["key":Student_Key.FirstName.rawValue,
                       "value": String(describing: studentData[Student_Key.FirstName.rawValue])])
    arrStudent.append(["key":Student_Key.LastName.rawValue,
                       "value": String(describing: studentData[Student_Key.LastName.rawValue])])
    //You have to add all keys mannualy

    arrMother.append(["key":Father_Key.Name.rawValue,
                      "value": String(describing: studentData[Father_Key.Name.rawValue])])
    arrMother.append(["key":Father_Key.Mobile.rawValue,
                      "value": String(describing: studentData[Father_Key.Mobile.rawValue])])

    arrFather.append(["key":Mother_Key.Name.rawValue,
                      "value": String(describing: studentData[Mother_Key.Name.rawValue])])
    arrFather.append(["key":Mother_Key.Mobile.rawValue,
                      "value": String(describing: studentData[Mother_Key.Mobile.rawValue])])

    yourTable.reloadData()
}
```

3) Return section, which you already implemented.

4) Return number of rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if indexPath.section == SEC_STUDENT
    {
        return arrStudent.count
    }
    else if indexPath.Section ==  SEC_FATHER
    {
        return arrFather.count
    }
    else if indexPath.Section == SEC_MOTHER
    {
        return arrMother.count
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

5) Load cell for index

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier") as! YourCell

    let dictData :  [String:Any]

    if indexPath.section == SEC_STUDENT
    {
        dictData = arrStudent[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]

    }
    else if indexPath.Section ==  SEC_FATHER
    {
        dictData = arrFather[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
    }
    else if indexPath.Section == SEC_MOTHER
    {
        dictData = arrayData[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
    }

    cell.lblKey =  data["key"]
    cell.lblValue = data["value"]
    return cell
}
```

** **Notes**

1) It may be your requirement but this is not a correct way to handle and show json.

2) Currently you can only show on student record then it should be detail page of student.

3) I just typed code to show way to achieve your goal. You have to handle things in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. I'm using custom cell with two labels one for the key and another for the value and want to fetch the all details about student, father and mother. how to achieve the same?.will you please update your answer for same?. thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, I'm having a custom cell with 2 labels for this.

Comment: Then you have to add create 3 array and have to parse each key.

Comment: will you elaborate with code? or else you can update your answer according to this so that I can accept it.sir thats the point on which I've stucked since few days :( . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its mam , yes i can update answer. But if you want it in this way it may be not correct. It will  work if you have only one student record. You can't so multiple student record in way you are trying to maintain.

Comment: And you have to code it your own, i am not available for 2 days. Happy Weekend

Comment: mam so in which way i have to implement this? please guide me when you are having a time.Thank you so much.Happy weekend to you too :) .

Comment: I think you should try it yourself. There are thousands of way but all depends on your need.

Comment: yes thank you @chanWarde2 i changed my design according to my need :)